# Configuring Spring Security for X509 client authentication, it isn't prompting browser for certificate

Tags: authentication, spring-security, x509

I'm trying to enable an application to use Client-Auth security with spring.  Here's my configuration:

```
  <security:http pattern="/api/**" >
<security:x509 subject-principal-regex="CN=(.*?)," 
  user-service-ref="x509UserService" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" requires-channel="https" />
</security:http>
```

If I don't configure anything within web.xml or tomcat's server.xml, the browser is never prompted to send along a certificate with the request.  Consequently, it always return null in in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.x509.X509AuthenticationFilter.extractClientCertificate(HttpServletRequest) method.

Is there something special that needs to be configured to have Spring participate in the SSL flow and request the client certificate?

Any help would be appreciated.

If I specify clientAuth='want' in the server.xml connector configuration, this has the undesirable side-effect of prompting everyone for certificates regardless of if they're accessing the /api path.

Similarly, if I specify the login-config and auth-method to be CLIENT-CERT, it also challenges the user, but then I would basically have to duplicate all of the cert checking I'd be doing in spring (or so it would seem).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your current java and build variety, at the very minimum you would either need to include something similar to the

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <filter-class>
     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
   </filter-class>
 </filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

or if you're using Java configuration with spring...

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer 
   extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
 }
```